# smiley validation not working in android

Tags: android, validation, special-characters

I have EditText, in that we can enter all keyboard characters like alphanumerics, smileys, special characters.

I have to validate for some special characters and all smileys not to be allowed. Needs to show all the entered non-allowed characters as **alert dialog**.

I tried with many smileys, for smileys it is taking only empty spaces inside the below function and for validation it is showing only one smiley, sometimes it is showing two.

Below is the code.

```
public static String validateSpecialCharacters(String message, Pattern messagePattern){
    StringBuilder matchedCharacters = new StringBuilder();
    Map<Character, Integer> uniqueSpecialCharacters = new HashMap<>();
    Matcher m = messagePattern.matcher(message);
    while (m.find()){
        if(!uniqueSpecialCharacters.containsKey(message.charAt(m.start()))) {
            uniqueSpecialCharacters.put(message.charAt(m.start()), 1);
            matchedCharacters.append(message.substring(m.start(),m.end()));
        }
    }
    return matchedCharacters.toString();
}
```

Inside the while the if condition is getting true only once or twice. But I have entered different smileys. The issue is the previous key added for the first smiley is similar with the second. But actually the smiley's are not similar. How to solve this.

Comment: try to disable smiley for that edittext

Comment: No the requirement is, allow to type all the characters and displaying the alert message with not allowed characters.

Comment: i have added another code,try it